# Should a tree map be scrollable?

Tags: info-visualisation, scrolling, tree

Here a non-scrollable version, all items are visible though smallest nodes tends to be a little too small, but it looks like a tree map:

[image]

Here is the same tree map but twice as large and scrollable like the Windows 8 UX-style, now items are larger but size differences are less obvious between them. And as a side-effect, since the tree map has more space, it tends to squarify the items making it look like more a grid than a tree map:

[image]

[image]

**Question:**

Do you know if there has been any research on the question that whether tree maps should be scrollable, or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tree map is based on [filling the available space](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~ben/papers/Johnson1991Tree.pdf) which suggests, but does not decree, there are no scroll bars. In any tree map, there may be values too small to display well. That is the nature of tree maps. They provide an overview of the hierarchy structure and the attributes of nodes in the hierarchy. If it is necessary to provide the user access to lower levels in the hierarchy where the nodes might be too small to be viewable from the top level, then consider zooming rather than scrolling.